# Creating a "fictional" last name, meaning "wild card"

Tags: vocabulary, translation-check, names

I am on a quest to create a new last name for myself.

I like the idea of "wildcard," particularly in the computing sense: as a placeholder for anything, however I want something that sounds more like a last name than just using "wildcard." (I also don't want my name to be poor translation, like a regrettable tattoo of a Chinese character that actually means "spicy chicken.")

So my question is, does the following capture my intention?

**Feracarta** or **Cartafera**?

In the searching I've done, "fera" seems to more commonly refer to wild animals in particular, rather than a more general wild: "ferox," which seems like more of the meaning I'd like to capture (headstrong, courageous, fierce), but "ferox" does not combine together as well into a name, in my opinion.

I haven't been able to find "carta" in a Latin dictionary, but it came up in the the etymology of "card" on Google, so that part could be totally incorrect?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would it make sense to reformulate the question as asking for a good Latin translation for the concept of "wildcard"? My point is that the best Latin translation might well be two or more words spelled separately (like *carta fera* if that is indeed the optimal choice), and it might be more interesting to others in that form. You could then spell the whole thing together to form a name in the end. (This is just an idea; it's your call.)

Comment: The *-fer, -ferus,* or *-fera* endings imply 'carrier' or 'bearer'. *-fera* would be misleading, I think.

Comment: Yes, *Cartafera* would likely be taken as meaning something like "bearing a card".  I suspect we need something other than a calque on "wild+card" here, but I have no good suggestions.

Comment: *Ne gry* is rare Latin for 'not a hint,' 'not a jot.' *Gry* is a non-committal grunt. How about *Grycarta* ?

Comment: For questions of this type, it's sometimes instructive to look at what the modern descendants of Latin do. In French, 'wildcard' in the context of both cards and computing can be joker; in Italian, it can be jolly (from jolly joker) for cards and carattere jolly for computing; in Spanish, it seems to be comodín (= 'joker') in both contexts; so, to avoid a calque, if that's important, one option would be to use something like joculator (m.)/joculatrix (f.), or scurra. Unfortunately, these don't at all capture what you seem to want for your name (hence this is a comment instead of an answer).

Comment: Have you considered [_factotum_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/factotum)? Its use as a single word is medieval Latin and conveys your meaning at least in part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this conveys the connotation you want, but here is my idea:

You search for a placeholder, so just use the placholder-names the Romans used when writing legal formulas: Aulus Agerius for the actor and Numerius Negidius for the defendant (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerius_Negidius))

If *agere* and *negare* do not fit, you can use the idea of this play on words with other verbs.

Answer (score 1):

**Varius vir, varii viri**

There is a board game in (Oxford) Corpus Christi library, Alea Evangelii, with four *special* pawns which (some think) change mid-game; they're called the multicoloured pawns, or the speckled pawns: *varii viri*, *varios viros*. But perhaps that's too far from your original idea. *Varia mulier, Varia femina, Varia iuvenis.*

**Grycarta**

[*Ne gry*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kXdmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP932&lpg=PP932&dq=%22ne%20gry%22%20Latin&source=bl&ots=I3RfqEnEoG&sig=9ljkfwhIuhTijzXN0G2L4EBzNfQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimkqHslL3YAhWjK8AKHZ18B68Q6AEIQDAF#v=onepage&q=%22ne%20gry%22%20Latin&f=false) is rare Latin for 'not a hint,' 'not a jot.' *Gry* is a non-committal grunt, so the wild idea is preserved. And *'gry'* is a word borrowed from Greek, a grunt; with the alternative roots *'gryx, gryz'* from the verb. So that's quite sophisticated. How about *Grycarta* ?

**Liber liber**

is a free book, meaning a blank book; so perhaps *Liberacarta.*

**Feracarta,** suggests wild and slightly out of control. I think it's better than any of my suggestions, all the same.

Comment: Can you explain "*Ne gry* is 'rare' Latin"? I've never seen "gry" used as a grunt before, the "ne" seems ungrammatical, and I don't see the connection with hint/jot.

Comment: @brianpck, Hugh is shortening it from *ne gry quidem* (in a way that I'm not sure quite works). The phrase is from somewhere in Plautus and possibly other places.

Comment: It may only exist in dictionaries. The link gives one of the two entries I've seen. Yet another entry gave *Ne gry quidem* translating 'Not a whit,' and led to the Greek stems, and mentioned the literal translation, not even an unrecognisable sound, not even a grunt.

Comment: @cnread Degrees of awfulness: in your opinion which is worse in citation, Plautus, or Erasmus?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in a comment by cnread, many languages render "wildcard" as "joker" in one way or another.
This happens in both Romance and other languages.
Therefore a good translation for the term "wildcard" itself might be something like *ioculator*, *nugator*, *balatro*, or *scurra*.
Pick [a Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) and look up "joker" or "jester" to find more.
However, these words will not make a good last name, unless you are fine with silly connotations.

Another point raised in the comments (by Hugh) is that *-fer* or *-fera* means a carrier.
For example, *aurifer(a)* carries gold and *ensifer(a)* carries a sword.
Therefore, in a Latin context, the ending *-fera* will not be easily connected with the adjective [*fera*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=ferus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).

It is possible to combine these two observations.
A joker is a "joke-bearer", and that could be rendered in Latin as *iocifera* (as a feminine version).
Instead of [*iocus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=jocus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), you could also try [*nugae*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=nugae&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) or [*ludus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=ludus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
Of these options *ludus* seems least ridiculous, so how about *ludifera*?
It could be understood as "wildcard", but also as "someone who brings games or spectacles".
If this together with a hint of wildness with *fera* sounds reasonable in your context, this is my suggestion.